# Quick predicate logic homework check

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

We only started learning identity as well as "only one," "at least one," etc. today. So if my answers are wrong, please provide me in the right direction.

1. Dionysius and Pseudo-Dionysius cannot be identical. For Dionysius was a member of the Court of Aeropagus, and Pseudo-Dionysius wasn't.

   d = Dionysius, p = Pseudo-Deionysius, a = the Court of Aeropagus, M_ _ = _ is a member of _

> Mda v ¬ Mdp ⊢ d $\ne$ p

2. Cisco loves Tessa and so does Rudi. Rudi is an acrobat and Cisco is not. Therefore at least 2 people love Tessa. Assume a domain of people.

   c = Cisco, t = Tessa, r = Rudi, L_ _ = _ loves _ , A_ = _is an acrobat

> Lct ∧ Lrt, Ar ∨ ¬Ac ⊢ ∃x∃y(Lxt ∧ Lyt)

1. Of all idealists, only Berkeley has won enduring philosophical fame. Only one bishop of Cloyne has won enduring philosophical fame, and he was an idealist. Therefore Berkeley was bishop of Cloyne.

   I_ = _ was an idealist, B_ _ = _ is a bishop of _, W _ = _ has won enduring philosophical fame, b = Berkeley, c = Cloyne

> Ib ∧ Wb ∧ ∀((Ix ∧ Wx) → x = b), ∃x(Ix ∧ Wx ∧ Bxc ∧ ∀y((Iy ∧ Wy ∧ Byc) → x = y)) ⊢ Bbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The $\lor $ should be an $\land$, and it should be $Mpa$, not $Mdp$. So: $Mda \land \neg Mpa \vdash d \not = p$
2. Again, the $\lor$ should be a $\land$. Also, add $x\not = y$ to the conclusion
3. Drop the $Iy$ from the second premise

Comment: Yeah those should be ∧ , not sure why I put ∨..

    2) Lct ∧ Lrt, Ar ∨ ¬Ac ⊢ ∃x∃y(Lxt ∧ Lyt ∧ x ≠ y) , would it be like this?
    3) ∃x(Ix ∧ Wx ∧ Bxc ∧ ∀y((Wy ∧ Byc) → x = y)) , would it be like this?

Comment: You are *still* using $\lor$ when its $\land$.  $~\mathrm Lct\land \mathrm Lrt, \mathrm Ar\mathop{\color{red}{\land}} \neg \mathrm Ac~\vdash~ \exists x\exists y (\mathrm Lxt\wedge \mathrm Lyt\wedge x\neq y)$

Comment: Sorry, I copy and pasted and forgot to change it.
Could you please explain why for 3), the Iy from premise 2 got dropped?

Comment: @K.Wong yes, your new 3 is what you want: the $Iy$ should not be in there since the claim is that this person $x$ is the only bishop that has won fame; it does not say that $x$ is the only idealist bishop that has won fame. Yes, we are told that $x$ is an idealist, but that's why you add the $Ix$ at the beginning, but the other part of the sentence does not make any reference to being an idealist. Put differently: if you put in the $Iy$, then $x$ would be the only idealist bishop who won fame, but that means that there could be other (non-idealist) bishops who won fame ...

Comment: @Bram28 Okay that makes sense. Also, how would I prove that d ≠ p?

Comment: @K.Wong Oh! It's because you actually have another small mistake in 1. Let me add that to my answer. I think you will then see it.